# How to authenticate a Lift REST web service client?

Tags: web-services, scala, authentication, rest, lift

I am developing a REST web service with Scala and LIFT and nave hardly any good idea on how to authenticate a client. I was thinking about a standard HTTP authentication, but found out it is very insecure as it passes passwords over a network in b64-encoded plain text. So how do I better do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want authentication to be secure against being observed in transit, your only realistic option is HTTPS.  Technically, there are key-exchange protocols like Diffie-Hellman, but they aren't widely supported.

But the problem of observing packets in flight is almost a nonexistent one.  In a shared LAN, it is *possible*, though not necessarily easy, to use a tap like FireSheep -- but it typically would be easier and more effective to walk over to the guy's computer and install a key-logger.

Comment: +2 for HTTPS, -1 for downplaying the threat of clear text :-)  If it needs to be super-secure, and you have a secure way to pre-share keys with clients, mutual authentication with certificates you roll yourself are completely standard and as secure as you make them.

Comment: @Szocske -- if someone can point to losses due to clear-text interception totaling, oh, 0.1% of the losses of mishandled passwords (or keyloggers or phishing or any of a half-dozen other real problems), I'll stop downplaying the threat.  Until then, I'll take the net +1 where I can.

Comment: You are welcome on the net +1 :-) Just remember zero point epsilon percent is still lots of real people and real suffering at "Internet scale" where your user base can be millions. With Internet cafes, free wifi, and oppressive regimes, it's kind of rude not to provide a safe option for those who keep their machines clean of the 99.9% vectors.

Comment: @Szocske - I don't disagree with your math but every feature costs something.  If I were writing, say, a Stack Overflow clone and had to worry that OMG, some hacker in a Starbuck's might steal a password and post an abusive comment, then I'd spend my time, I don't know, implementing a better editor rather than worrying about it.  If my site had anything to do with money, then yes, HTTPS all the way.

Answer (score 0):

Basic authentication will pass password and user name in (nearly) clear text. If you use digest authentication instead it will still be prone to man-in-the-middle eavesdropping, but you should be safer from password theft and session takeover. This chapter in Exploring Lift have some information about digest authentication in lift: http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-9.html

Comment: But they suggest stateful dispatch, I'd prefer to stay stateless if possible.